# How to get value from user in java for array?

Tags: java, arrays

This is the part of my program. when I run it on eclipse it shows error ..
Please tell me correct and simple way to get values from user for array.
and also please tell me what is the mistake in my program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("enter how many  array element  you want to take");

       int num= input.nextInt();
       int array[]= new int[num];
       System.out.println("enter all array elements");
       for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++);
       {
         array[j]=input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("array elements are: " );

    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you show the error that eclipse gives?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 j cannot be resolved to a variable

 at tutorial10.apps.main(apps.java:69) this is the error

Comment: As far as displaying array elements goes, I suggest doing either of the following: 1) import `java.util.Arrays` and add `Arrays.toString(array)` to the end of your `System.out.println` statement, or 2) use `for (int i : array)` to display your elements manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must **delete the-semi colon** at the end of the for-loop here:

```
for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++); // delete this semi-colon
       {
```

A semi-colon ends a statement in Java, when you write a for-loop you need to give it a body between braces `{}`

Comment: No worries, if this is the answer you were looking for you can tick it correct :)